# System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission error on local SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, assemblies

I am modifying a SSRS Report via VS2015 on my local machine. The rdl uses a custom assembly I get the error 'System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.' when trying to preview the report

I have the reference added to the report and added this section to RSPreviewPolicy.config and rssrvpolicy.config

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup"
       version="1"
       PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
       Name="MyCustomCodeGroup"
       Description="Code group for my data processing extension">
  <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition"
                version="1"
                  Url="C:\Reporting\SSRSAssemblyFile\ReportingDrawing.dll"/>
</CodeGroup>
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong or anything else to try. The report does work on the SSRS server.

Thanks,
Hank

Comment: am facing same issue. was there a solution to this issue?

Comment: I was able to get this working by editing the config files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies. The files were also in the project folder which had no effect on the SSRS on my local machine, I had previously added the files to the gobal assembly cache using gacutil. Hope that helps.

Comment: am not debugging locally. am deploying in my qa env which has no visual studio.

Comment: I never had an issue on the ssrs server - only my local machine. You have to check the RSPreviewPolicy.config and rssrvpolicy.config files as well as make sure you have run the gacutil on the dll (be sure to be an admin).